# Is there a way to get Events and report search from Deep security python SDK?

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, deepsecurity

We are creating python script that can fetch Deep security anti-malware event details and create CSV file with the following field.

1) Computer name
  2) last scheduled scan time
  3) Number of malware found
  4) Pattern version 
  5) last pattern update date and time

I am not able to find SDK document that can help me get events generated in last scheduled scan.

Answer (score 1):

The API provides access to Computer name, last scheduled scan time, and pattern version. It does not provide access to events, however the legacy REST api does:

- https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/12_5/use-the-previous-rest-api
- https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/legacy-rest/12_5/index.html?env=dsaas#overview

There is only a Java SDK that is supported, but as you probably know you can use Python to make HTTP requests to a REST API.

An old Python SDK was provided for the legacy REST and SOAP API's (not supported past Deep Security 10.3) -- it might be worth trying although there is no official support and no guarantee of results: https://github.com/deep-security/deep-security-py

Finally, I'm not sure if this is covers what you need but there is a powershell script that uses the legacy REST API to retrieve computer-related events for a specific time frame: https://github.com/deep-security/ops-tools/blob/master/deepsecurity/manager-apis/powershell/get-computerCreatedEvents.ps1

Hope that helps. Maybe somebody else can add to what I know of.

-- Scott (Deep Security content developer)